Any alternative in Logback to MDC to allow custom fields?
I have a log format where I would like to add an attribute with a code to represent that event - I only know the code before all operations. The example output could be:
{ "@timestamp": "...", "@level": "...", "message": "Transaction saved", "code": "APP.010" }

I really don't want to concatenate code on message, it must be an attribute and I am wondering what is the proper way to achieve it using logback-logstash?
I know that Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC) could be useful if I need to log same value accross all log messages but this is not my case.
Is there any option besides MDC to add a custom field? What is the right way?
My app is Java 15 with Spring Boot 3 using Logback.
logger.info(new LogObject("APP.010", "Transaction Saved"));


Can you add java snippet of logger.info() on how you are logging the message with code etc.,?. logback-logstash has few options so want to see how you are doing the logging now.

I think you need to implement custom provider, and add it to your logback-spring.xml config

@Imran I have added the snippet. Could you check?

Have you tried StructuredArguments from logstash logback encoder?. Example: import static net.logstash.logback.argument.StructuredArguments.*; logger.info("Transaction Saved", value("code","APP.010")); This should create JSON Log Entry like {"message":"Transaction Saved", "code": "APP.010"}Let me know if this what you are looking for, I will provide working sample.
